# How do you expand all elements in the WebKit Inspector elements view?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, inspector

Is there a way to expand all elements in the elements view of the Chrome WebKit inspector?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm wondering myself and I just found this question through Google. Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you hold <kbd>ctrl + alt</kbd> for windows (just <kbd>opt</kbd> on a mac) while clicking on the arrow of the element you want to expand, it will expand and all of its children will expand.  So, if you <kbd>ctrl + alt</kbd> click on the `<html>` tag, that should expand the entire page.

This [Link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts) lists the keyboard shortcuts for chrome dev tools, including that one.

Comment: Just holding Alt and clicking works for me on Windows - thanks

Comment: Saved me a few attempts, trying to screenshot code before the redirect timer kicks in :D

Comment: Just `Alt` on Linux.

Comment: Shift+Alt on ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ALT</kbd> + LEFTCLICK

Answer (score 5):

Here's how i've decided to do it:

Highlight the element tag I wish to inspect, if it's the whole (expand all) the requirement, then highlight `<body>` tag, click F2.

Note: F2 is actually the shortcut for 'Toggle edit as HTML'. You can directly make any change in this mode, changes are reflected on web page. You may right-click within this new code view-window and enable/disable wordwrap.

Comment: boom. Just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: It works, thanks. An additional wish is for that editable content to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome while clicking the arrow in the source-code, will expand all children elements.

- ALT + Click the Drop Arrow = Unwrap One level by one
- ALT + CTRL + Click the Drop Arrow = Unwrap "All" Level at once

Answer (score 1):

Click on the element:

- Alt + Right Arrow (Expand)
- Alt + Left Arrow (Collapse)

You can move around with the Arrow keys and using Tab.

Answer (score 1):

these approaches seem convoluted, all you have to do to make all the arrow symbols change from pointing towards the right to pointing down is click the html tag and in the dropdown box click "expand recursively"

Answer (score 0):

I found just right clicking on the  tag and selecting "Expand Recursively" worked for me. I'm using Chrome Version 66.

You can also right click and "Collapse Children" to collapse it all again.