# Expand all element in google chrome inspect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to expand all elements in inspect chrome supports.

How can I do this?

Is there any extensions or tool chrome supports?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410212/how-do-you-expand-all-elements-in-the-webkit-inspector-elements-view

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Expand / collapse node and all its children**

Mac: <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Click on arrow icon</kbd>

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click on arrow icon</kbd>

To expand all elements, use the `<html>` element's arrow icon in the shortcut.

Source: [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)

Comment: Anyone know if there's a linux version of this?  I've tried many key combinations, and none of them seem to work.

Comment: I'm struggling as to why this is not working for me.  Even using the right-click menu option for the arrow on the element and choosing Expand All only open a single level below and not all children.  Ideas?  Been checking settings, have latest version

Comment: This seems to have stopped working for (at least) version 61 :(

Comment: Hold Alt then click Expand > is how you do it in version 64.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing you're trying to expand all elements in the console to perform a search. If that's the case, you can right-click on the logged element and save that log. Then open it in any text editor. But you have to right-click in an empty area of the logged element line. [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI5L8.png). As mentioned in this discussion, it may be a lot, like, really a lot of information.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider leaving a comment instead.